# How to define a function that takes an argumente outside the paranthesis like names()

Tags: r, function, side-effects

today I came across a question. Normaly every function in R takes arguments within its belonging paranthesis, e.g.

```
# function definition
f <- function(arg){print(arg)}
# function call
f(arg = 3)
```

But the built-in function `names()`, for example, works differently. You would call it like so:

```
x = 3
names(x) <- "aNumber"
```

This seems to be special, since the value `"aNumber"` is not assigned to the function `names()` as a conventional argument, but rather *assigned to the function itself*. So my question is how to define such type of functions.

Cheers,

Philipp

Comment: I suspect, this is to be solved by means of object-oriented programming in R.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a *User defined infix operator* like:

```
`%x%` <- function(a, b) {a * b}
2 %x% 3
#[1] 6
```

a *User defined replacement / assignment function* like:

```
`x<-` <- function(x, value) {x * value}
y  <- 2
x(y) <- 3
y
#[1] 6
```

See also: [3.4.4 Subset assignment](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment) or [6.8 Function forms](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#function-forms).

Comment: Hi Gki,

thank you for your answer. As you correctly pointed out, what I am trying to define is a _replacement operator_. It is interesting to remark, that the argument **"value"** seems to be a requirement when defining such operators.

Comment: if I rename the argument "value" to something else, e.g. "val" I get the following error message:

Error in `x<-`(`*tmp*`, value = 3) : unused argument (value = 3)

Furthermore, these operators seem to "violate" the functional programming paradigm of R, since these special functions have a side effect, i.e. they manipulate the assigned argument y.

Normally, (if not using the <<- operator) I would not expect an R-function to alter the value of an argument in the parent environment.